# Stop execution of list on Button Click

Tags: wrapper-class

I have created a wrapper class in my code. When I click a Button then this list of wrapper is automatically called along with method .Is there any way to stop execution of stop list on button click.

```
Method :-
public PageReference addRow(){ 
// getAllSchedules();javascript:DatePicker.insertDate('2/24/2015', 'j_id0:j_id2:j_id29:j_id86:3:j_id88:4:j_id90', true);
 system.debug('TEST THE ADD ROW BUTTON :::::: '+lstToDisplay.size()); 
toDisplay td = new toDisplay (); 
td.isFirstObj = true; 
td.sObj = QueryBuilderUtility.createObject (objConfigurationQuery.sObject_4__c); 
td.children = new List<toDisplay> (); 
lstToDisplay.add(td) ; 
return null; 
} 



Wrapper List:- 
public List<toDisplay> getAllSchedules() {
 toDisplay td = new toDisplay (); 
System.debug('!!!1'+td); 
td.sObj = QueryBuilderUtility.createObject (objConfigurationQuery.sObject_4__c); 
System.debug('!!!2'+td.sobj); 
lstToDisplay.add(td); 
System.debug('!!!3'+lstToDisplay); 
return lstToDisplay; 
}
```

Comment: method:-  public PageReference addRow(){
       // getAllSchedules();javascript:DatePicker.insertDate('2/24/2015', 'j_id0:j_id2:j_id29:j_id86:3:j_id88:4:j_id90', true);
       system.debug('TEST THE ADD ROW BUTTON :::::: '+lstToDisplay.size());
       toDisplay td = new toDisplay ();
                    td.isFirstObj = true;
                    td.sObj = QueryBuilderUtility.createObject (objConfigurationQuery.sObject_4__c);
                    td.children = new List<toDisplay> ();
                    
                    lstToDisplay.add(td) ;
                  
        return null;
      }

Comment: Wrapper List:- public List<toDisplay> getAllSchedules() {
        toDisplay td = new toDisplay ();
        System.debug('!!!1'+td);
        td.sObj = QueryBuilderUtility.createObject (objConfigurationQuery.sObject_4__c);
         System.debug('!!!2'+td.sobj);
        lstToDisplay.add(td);
         System.debug('!!!3'+lstToDisplay);
       
    return lstToDisplay;
    }

Comment: you can edit your post and add the code directly to it in more readable format

Answer (score 0):

Do Like This...

```
 public List<toDisplay> AllSchedules {get;set;}
    public className(){
        //constructor
        toDisplay td = new toDisplay (); 
        System.debug('!!!1'+td); 
        td.sObj = QueryBuilderUtility.createObject (objConfigurationQuery.sObject_4__c); 
        System.debug('!!!2'+td.sobj); 
        lstToDisplay.add(td); 
        System.debug('!!!3'+lstToDisplay); 
    }
```

initilise your list in class constructor

I think this might be usefull for you if i am wrong then correct me.